# Blank page without ".php" extension

Tags: php

I'm currently been trying to figure out how to remove `.php` extension from URL bar. However when I remove `.php` it gives me a blank white page.

Could someone please be able to explain why this would be happening?

I've added to the `php.ini`: `expose_php=Off`

and also got this in my `.htaccess`:

```
   # Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Then started to write the following for `URL`:

```
<?php 
    function parseCurrentURL() {
        $pageURL = 'http';
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
    }

    if(parse_url(parseCurrentURL(), PHP_URL_PATH)){
        $url = parse_url(parseCurrentURL(), PHP_URL_PATH);
        switch(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1)){
            case 'forums':

                break;
        }
    }


?>
```

Example with `.php`:

[image]

Example without `.php`:

[image]

Comment: The `.php` isn't just optional. Sites which omit php suffix will be using some sort of complex rewriting in Apache or the like to achieve this. Normally they'll just be delivering index.php but spoofing the path using server directives. The alternative would be to make the path `forums/index.php`

Comment: @MattFletcher Please check my updated answer

Comment: Oh okay. `expose_php` only hides the header though, so don't think that really means anything in the context of this question. But I'm not really sure about the rewrite rule, not my strongest skill

Comment: You can omit file extensions with the [`MultiViews` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). There's no need to involve `mod_rewrite`

Comment: But the rule isn't rewriting is it? It's just 404ing? That won't by itself make non .php work, I'd imagine? Also apologies, on phone and return button keeps submitting prematurely!

Comment: @MattFletcher - If someone goes to the `.php` url so like forums.php then it'll throw a 404 error

Comment: Okay, but that will just make forums _and_ forums.php not work. There's still nothing there that allows the no-extension version. But the comment above me is probably onto something.

Comment: Would you show us your google chrome's console? by hitting F12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is my htaccess code check if this work for you

```
# Default directory
DirectoryIndex index.php

# ERROR FILES
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /page500.php

# Remove the need for www in Your URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxx.pt$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xxxx.pt/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude administrador folder
RewriteRule ^(administrador)($|/) - [L]

# Rewrite URLs
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

##Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved with apache .htaccess configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

more information here https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

I current use this code in my .htaccess to remove the extension .php and I never get a blank page

```
# Rewrite URLs
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: All your CSS and JS directories Work? and do you route your URLs through your main index.php? and just check what pages you're on with URL?

Comment: yes all my files works well without any problem... if you want I can share with you the code that I have in htaccess file

Comment: That would be great. Thanks Daniel. Send me an email: chrisbeckett13@yahoo.co.uk

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with your `.htaccess` file?